# Каждому элементу одного списка (массива) присвоить каждый элемент других списков (массивов)

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, php, преобразование

Запарился уже, никак не могу понять, как же сделать.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть словарь, содержащий списки, (Python),
например, вот содержит три таких списка:

```
{0: ['34', '35'], 1: ['green', 'blue', 'black'], 2: ['41', '42']}
```

Нужно каждому элементу одного списка присвоить каждый элемент других списков.
На выходе должно быть так:

```
 - 34 green 41
 - 34 green 42
 - 34 blue 41
 - 34 blue 42
 - 34 black 41
 - 34 black 42
 - 35 green 41
 - 35 green 42
 - 35 blue 41
 - 35 blue 42
 - 35 black 41
 - 35 black 42
```

Количество списков и элементов в них произвольное.

---

Ну или то же самое на php. Есть массив, например:

```
$mass = array(0 => array('34', '35', '36', '37'), 1 => array('green', 'ble', 'black'), 2 => array('41', '42', '43'));
```

Comment: "Если идею сложно реализовать - значит идея плоха!" Зачем ломать голову, если можно перестроить исходных словарь!?

Comment: Для решения задачи, исходные данные именно такие..

Comment: @G2100636, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке питона есть замечательный модуль itertools, который как раз умеет то, что вам нужно:

```
import itertools
d = {0: ['34', '35'], 1: ['green', 'blue', 'black'], 2: ['41', '42']}
for items in itertools.product(*d.values()):
    print ' '.join(items)
```

Comment: Спасибо!
волшебно)) то что нужно)

Answer (score 1):

Простой вариант для понимания:

```
d = {0: ['34', '35'], 1: ['green', 'blue', 'black'], 2: ['41', '42']};

for a in d[0]:
  for b in d[1]:
    for c in d[2]:
      print(str(a) + " " + str(b) + " " + str(c))
```

Ну и как-то так на php. =)

Comment: Спасибо!
получилось, но в так можно сделать только для заранее известного числа списков..